# Split a string on reaching certain characters in java

Tags: java, regex, string, split

This is my input string:

> Look -  to make links (10) fresh apple (9) This is Apple (7) returns para (6,8) in foot (5)

I want to split it into the following parts:

```
Look -  to make links (10)
fresh apple (9)
This is Apple (7)
returns para (6,8)
in foot (5)
```

I tried splitting using

```
string.split("(");
```

but didn't work.

I thought of eliminating all the '()' from the string so it will have only digits. So , how to split and push it to a new line if it contains a digit followed by a space ? For ex :

```
yy, 2009 Look -  to make links
```

then, the line `"Look -  to make links"` must come in next line as there is a digit followed by a space.

NOTE: I want to start reading and manipulating the string only from "2009" . ie. The line  "Look -  to make links" must be the first line .The String is a dynamic one. So, I can't do an index based calculation.
Any idea of how to do it ?

Comment: So you want to remove everything before `2009` (inclusive), split before the two `(`, and remove the word `surrounded`? Sounds like a job for a regular expression match. You should learn how to do regular expressions.

Comment: BTW: `string.split("(")` doesn't work because the argument is a regular expression and `(` has special meaning in a regular expression. You should learn how to do regular expressions.

Comment: Yea I want to remove everything before 2009 and print it new line if the string contains a space followed by '(' @Andreas

Comment: And remove the word `surrounded`?

Comment: No need to remove the digits if its surrounded by ( ). See my expected output @Andreas

Comment: Two options: 1) Use `indexOf("2009")`, `indexOf('(')` (twice), and calls to `substring()`. 2) Learn how to do regular expressions.

Comment: You could use a regular expression, but I imagine you want to parse more than just this one line?  Do you have more examples you need to parse so that we can create a regex that will work in general?

Comment: I have edited my question as well as expected output @CarlosBribiescas

Comment: Option 3) Convert to char array. Inspect every value. Take what you want out of char array. Not the best option, but an option

Comment: Have removed the words before the string "2009" and have updated the actual string in question .  Please look at it @CarlosBribiescas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell, but it seems this might be what you want:

```
String[] lines = str.split("(?<=\\))");
```

This splits after every close bracket, *retaining* the close bracket. The regex is a *look behind*, which has the form `(?<=...)`, for a (literal) close bracket. Look aheads/behinds are zero width assertions - so they don't consume any input; essential when you need to split but not lose any of the original content.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Could you please explain of what the above code does ? I am not familiar with regex @Bohemian

Comment: @Anusha FYI I have added an explanation

Answer (score 0):

Anusha's regex answer leaves spaces in front of 4/5 of the output. You can add a .trim() to remove those!

Here is another option. It is a "brute force" string manipulation, which is never very pretty.

```
    String str = "Look -  to make links (10) fresh apple (9)" +
            " This is Apple (7) returns para (6,8) in foot (5)";

    int startIndex = 0;
    int endIndex = str.indexOf(")")+1;
    while(endIndex < str.length())
    {
        System.out.println(str.substring(startIndex, endIndex)+"\n");
        startIndex = endIndex+1;
        endIndex = str.indexOf(")",startIndex)+1;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! It works tioo  !! Can you explain what does the regex  str.split("(?<=\\))"); do ? @Laszlo

Comment: @Anusha str.split("(?<=\\))") will result in an array where [0] looks perfect, but [1] through [4] have a space as their first character, followed by the string asked for by the OP. That is very, very close, and to trim that leading space one need only use .trim() to trim it out. The OP's requirements didn't show any extra leading space.  Oh!! And please forgive me, I added a \n in my println() based on the question BEFORE the edits, which seem to have removed the blank lines in the output. oops!